# Workbox StaleWhileRevalidate and offline fallback

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

Is it possible to return an offline fallback for StaleWhileRevalidate strategie with Workbox ?

```
const urlHandler = new StaleWhileRevalidate({
  cacheName: 'routes',
  plugins,
});

registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.mode === 'navigate',
  ({ event }) =>
    urlHandler.handle({ event }).catch(() => caches.match(FALLBACK_HTML_URL)),
);
```

This code work only if the request is on cache .. but for new URL not cached (but with network), it show directly the Offline fallback :/

Anyone have already test this usecase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Workbox v6+, the cleanest way to do this would be to use a [`handlerDidError`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#custom_plugins:%7E:text=%7D%2C-,handlerDidError,-%3A) plugin:

```js
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {StaleWhileRevalidate} from 'workbox-strategies';


registerRoute(
  ({request}) => request.mode === 'navigate',
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'routes',
    plugins: [
      {handlerDidError: () => caches.match(FALLBACK_HTML_URL)},
      // Add any other plugins here.
    ],
  })
);
```